# Simple countdown timer mm:ss

Tags: javascript, html, countdowntimer

I want to create a simple countdown timer.

I found something and its working for hours minute and seconds, I want only minutes:seconds...

how can I make the same timer for mm:ss format?

```
var seconds;
var temp;

function countdown() {
     time = document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML;
     timeArray = time.split(':')
     seconds = timeToSeconds(timeArray);

     if (seconds == '') {
          temp = document.getElementById('countdown');
          temp.innerHTML = "00:00:00";
          return;
     }

     seconds--;

     temp = document.getElementById('countdown');
     temp.innerHTML = secondsToTime(seconds);
     timeoutMyOswego = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
}

function timeToSeconds(timeArray) {
     var minutes = (timeArray[0] * 60) + (timeArray[1] * 1);
     var seconds = (minutes * 60) + (timeArray[2] * 1);
     return seconds;
}

function secondsToTime(secs) {
     var hours = Math.floor(secs / (60 * 60));
     hours = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours;

     var divisor_for_minutes = secs % (60 * 60);
     var minutes = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);
     minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;

     var divisor_for_seconds = divisor_for_minutes % 60;
     var seconds = Math.ceil(divisor_for_seconds);
     seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
     return hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
}

countdown();
```

here is the html

```
<div id="countdown">01:02:15</div>
```

Comment: what do you want just `02:15` or `62:15` ?

Comment: I want my countdown timer runs from 6:00 to backwards to 00:00 like backwards from 6 minutes

Comment: provide sample input and expected output. in question you gave hh:mm:ss , in comment you gave mm:ss .

Comment: simple is that I just want to put a 6 minutes countdown timer like this one 6:00 (mm:ss) .... above Is the countdown timer with hh:mm:ss .... I dont need hours....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP want us to do his job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var seconds;  
    var temp;
    console.clear();

    function countdown() {
         time = document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML;
         timeArray = time.split(':')
         seconds = timeToSeconds(timeArray);

         if (seconds == '') {
              temp = document.getElementById('countdown');
              temp.innerHTML = "00:00";

              return;
         }
         seconds--;
         temp = document.getElementById('countdown');
         temp.innerHTML= secondsToTime(seconds);
         timeoutMyOswego = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);        
    }

    function timeToSeconds(timeArray) {  
         var minutes = (timeArray[0] * 1);
         var seconds = (minutes * 60) + (timeArray[1] * 1);
         return seconds;
    }

    function secondsToTime(secs) {
         var hours = Math.floor(secs / (60 * 60));
         hours = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours;
         var divisor_for_minutes = secs % (60 * 60);
         var minutes = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);
         minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
         var divisor_for_seconds = divisor_for_minutes % 60;
         var seconds = Math.ceil(divisor_for_seconds);
         seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;            
         return  minutes + ':' + seconds;   
    }

    countdown();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/santoshj/jex1f8uv/

Comment: after 00:00 if you want to continue from beginning here is the updated fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/o6bjumc2/

Answer (score 1):

```
var countDownController = function(seconds){
  var countdownTimer = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);


  function startTimer(){
    var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
    var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
    var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
    var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
    var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if(minutes<10){
        minutes = "0"+ minutes;
    }
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
    }



    //        You can use which state you need!
    console.log(days+":"+minutes+":"+hours+":"+remainingSeconds)



    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);

        //state for end timing
        alert('time is up');

    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
}
};

var timeToCountDown = 1232321;
countDownController(timeToCountDown);
```